# JavaScript: Too many if-else statements?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm having a problem here with JS. I'm trying to make three lists of ingredients (for brewing potions) sorted by type, all of them are checkboxes within a  tag.

You are supposed to select (check) one element of each of the three lists in order to brew a potion. If you select the right ingredients and you press the "Brew potion" button, you have a determined potion, if you select three ingredients that don't match, it displays a

at the bottom of the page saying "It seems it didn't work this time!" after pressing the "Brew potion" button.

In JavaScript, I've used an array for each of the three lists, using the document.getElementById for each of the elements in each list. Then, I've used an *if* and several *else if* statements to build the formulas, with an *else* statement at the end, in case the wrong checkboxes are checked and no potion comes out of the selected ingredients.

Everything works fine until I have more than three *else if* statments! Only the *if* and the first three * else if* work, but not the rest of these nor the *else*, which worked fine when I only had three *else if*. It simply doesn't display the message on the  at the end except, again, for the first *if* and the first three *else if* statements.

I've shortened the code on purpose, leaving some ingredients and 'formulas' behind, in order not to overwhelm you. I've to say that sometimes several formulas use the same ingredient. I've tried chaning the numbers or erasing the *else if* for the formulas that use the same 'ingredient' but that doesn't work either.

I've revised the code several times, but couldn't find anything wrong. It really puzzles me.

```js
function pociones() {

  var plantas = [document.getElementById("acacia"), document.getElementById("aceitedecoco"), //0-1
    document.getElementById("aceitedeoliva"), document.getElementById("algafila"), //2-3
    document.getElementById("agrimonia"), document.getElementById("asafetida"), //4-5
    document.getElementById("asaro"), document.getElementById("azafran"), //6-7
    document.getElementById("bellota"), document.getElementById("cabezadetortuga"), //8-9
    document.getElementById("calendula"), document.getElementById("cardamomo"), //10-11
    document.getElementById("clavo"), document.getElementById("consuelda"), //12-13
    document.getElementById("digitalis"), document.getElementById("escrofularia"), //14-15
    document.getElementById("gomapersa"), document.getElementById("hinojo"), //16-17
    document.getElementById("junipero"), document.getElementById("polemonium"), //18-19
    document.getElementById("stachys")
  ]; //20

  var partes = [document.getElementById("cerebrodedemonio"), document.getElementById("cerebrodedragon"), //0-1
    document.getElementById("cerebrodegigante"), document.getElementById("cerebrodemedium"), // 2-3
    document.getElementById("corazondeleon"), document.getElementById("corazondeminotauro"), //4-5
    document.getElementById("corazondepegaso"), document.getElementById("ectoplasma"), //6-7
    document.getElementById("escamadedragondeoro"), document.getElementById("esenciadefuegofatuo"), //8-9
    document.getElementById("esenciadeelemental"), document.getElementById("esporasdehongochillon"), //10-11
    document.getElementById("glanduladeanimal"), document.getElementById("glandulademagoogro"), //12-13
    document.getElementById("higadodeluciogigante"), document.getElementById("nubedevampiro"), //14-15
    document.getElementById("pieldelicantropo"), document.getElementById("pieldesucubo"), //16-17
    document.getElementById("plumadehipogrifo"), document.getElementById("sangrededragon"), //18-19
    document.getElementById("sangredehombrerata"), document.getElementById("sangredeogromago"), //20-21
    document.getElementById("sangredeninfa"), document.getElementById("sangredeogro"), //22-23
    document.getElementById("sangredetroll"), document.getElementById("sudordegigante"), //24-25
    document.getElementById("talamohumano")
  ]; //26


  var gemas = [document.getElementById("alejandrita"), document.getElementById("azabache"), //0-1
    document.getElementById("coral"), document.getElementById("cornalia"), //2-3
    document.getElementById("crisoprasa"), document.getElementById("diamante"), //4-5
    document.getElementById("hematita"), document.getElementById("lapislazuli"), //6-7
    document.getElementById("malaquita"), document.getElementById("onix"), //8-9
    document.getElementById("piedradeluna"), document.getElementById("rubi"), //10-11
    document.getElementById("serpentina"), document.getElementById("turquesa"), //12-13
    document.getElementById("zafiro"), document.getElementById("zircon")
  ]; //14-15

  var texto;

  if (plantas[0].checked && partes[17].checked && gemas[10].checked) {
    texto = "¡Has hecho una poción de polimorfar!";
  } else if (plantas[1].checked && partes[0].checked && gemas[14].checked) {
    texto = "¡Has hecho aceite etéreo!";
  } else if (plantas[2].checked && partes[14].checked && gemas[8].checked) {
    texto = "¡Has hecho aceite resbaladizo!";
  } else if (plantas[3].checked && partes[19].checked && gemas[11].checked) {
    texto = "¡Has hecho una poción de longevidad!";
  } else if (plantas[4].checked && partes[25].checked && gemas[7].checked) {
    texto = "¡Has hecho una poción de fuerza de gigante!";
  } else if (plantas[4].checked && partes[21].checked && gemas[6].checked) {
    texto = "¡Has hecho una poción curación media!";
  } else if (plantas[5].checked && partes[4].checked && gemas[6].checked) {
    texto = "¡Has hecho una poción de heroísmo!";
  } else if (plantas[6].checked && partes[20].checked && gemas[4].checked) {
    texto = "¡Has hecho una poción de disminución!";
  } else if (plantas[7].checked && partes[8].checked && gemas[0].checked) {
    texto = "¡Has hecho una poción de encontrar tesoro!";
  } else if (plantas[8].checked && partes[13].checked && gemas[12].checked) {
    texto = "¡Has hecho una poción de crecimiento!";
  } else if (plantas[8].checked && partes[5].checked && gemas[2].checked) {
    texto = "¡Has hecho una poción de super-heroísmo!";
  } else if (plantas[10].checked && partes[26].checked && gemas[3].checked) {
    texto = "¡Has hecho una poción de clarividencia!";
  } else if (plantas[10].checked && partes[7].checked && gemas[4].checked) {
    texto = "¡Has hecho una poción de invisibilidad!";
  } else if (plantas[12].checked && partes[6].checked && gemas[13].checked) {
    texto = "¡Has hecho una poción de velocidad!";
  } else if (plantas[13].checked && partes[23].checked && gemas[6].checked) {
    texto = "¡Has hecho una poción de curación ligera!";
  } else {
    texto = "El brebaje preparado no ha dado resultado...";
  }

  document.getElementById("solucion").innerHTML = texto;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div id="alquimia">
    <div id="plantas">
      <h3>Plantas</h3>
      <input type="checkbox" id="acacia">Acacia o goma arábiga<br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="aceitedecoco">Aceite de coco<br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="aceitedeoliva">Aceite de oliva<br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="algáfila">Algáfila<br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="agrimonia">Agrimonia<br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="asafetida">Asafétida<br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="asaro">Ásaro<br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="azafran">Azafrán<br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="bellota">Bellota<br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="cabezadetortuga">Cabeza de tortuga<br>
    </div>
    <div id="partes">
      <h3>Partes de bestias</h3>
      <input type="checkbox" id="cerebrodedemonio">Cerebro de demonio<br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="cerebrodedragon">Cerebro de dragón<br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="cerebrodegigante">Cerebro de gigante<br>
      <!--Poción de control de gigante-->
      <input type="checkbox" id="cerebrodemedium">Cerebro de médium<br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="corazondeleon">Corazón de león<br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="corazondeminotauro">Corazón de minotauro<br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="corazondepegaso">Corazón de pegaso<br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="ectoplasma">Ectoplasma<br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="escamadedragondeoro">Escama de dragon de oro<br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="esenciadefuegofatuo">Esencia de fuego fatuo<br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="esenciadeelemental">Esencia de elemental<br>
    </div>
    <div class="gemas">
      <h3>Gemas</h3>
      <input type="checkbox" id="alejandrita">Alejandrita<br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="azabache">Azabache<br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="coral">Coral<br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="cornalia">Cornalia<br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="crisoprasa">Crisoprasa<br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <Button onclick="pociones()" type="button">¡Hacer poción!</Button>
</form>
<p id="solucion"></p>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Javier

PS - Sorry that all the 'id' and texts are in Spanish, hope is understandable despite of it.

Comment: That does not seem efficient at all.

Comment: The right approach here is using some kind of database - even if it's to be a static JSON file - that contains names of ingredients and groupings of potions. That way your code is several lines regardless of the number of ingredients and potions. In that case you have only one 'if', in a loop that searches whether current choices are a potion.

Comment: Just for the avoidance of doubt: There's no real limit on the number of `if`/`else if`/`else if` you can use. More than three is fine. If you want to use the structure above, use the powerful debugger built into your browser to go through the code step-by-step watching it run, to see where it's going wrong. It's easy (for instance) to leave out an `else`. If you want suggestions on how to improve the structure, that's probably a good fit over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You have a lot of items in three groups, `plantas` `partes` `gemas`. Why don't you give each of them a common class and select by it?

Comment: First of all, you would be doing so much better if you did something like this: `var plantas = document.getElementById('plantas').getElementsByTagName('input');` instead of getting every checkbox by id. The same for `partes` and `gemas`.

Answer (score 1):

Programming is all about automating processess. You will not hear me say that the way you are doing this is wrong. If it works then it is ok. But of course it would be more beautiful if you could find a way to make it check everything automatically. Like looping through all x cords and just check if all of those are checked. This may not be easier, but it will be more extendable. If you'd ever wish to play a game on a ten by ten grid. then you would only have to say that that is the size of the field. Right now you would need to add all those other lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate error:

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="algáfila">Algáfila<br>

  document.getElementById("algafila")
```

algáfila vs algafila - ID mismatch.

Your overall error: Going with repetitious code and data manually copied between three parts of code, instead of using some kind of common data source and iterating through it. That approach ALWAYS creates such errors.

Comment: This was indeed the mistake... Thank you for pointing that out. Don't know how I could not see that! *facepalm*

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are referencing:

```
  var gemas = [document.getElementById("alejandrita"), document.getElementById("azabache"), //0-1
document.getElementById("coral"), document.getElementById("cornalia"), //2-3
document.getElementById("crisoprasa"), document.getElementById("diamante"), //4-5
document.getElementById("hematita"), document.getElementById("lapislazuli"), //6-7
document.getElementById("malaquita"), document.getElementById("onix"), //8-9
document.getElementById("piedradeluna"), document.getElementById("rubi"), //10-11
document.getElementById("serpentina"), document.getElementById("turquesa"), //12-13
document.getElementById("zafiro"), document.getElementById("zircon") 
]; //14-15
```

elements that do not exist in your html:

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="alejandrita">Alejandrita<br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="azabache">Azabache<br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="coral">Coral<br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cornalia">Cornalia<br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="crisoprasa">Crisoprasa<br>
```

Comment: But as others have pointed out - your approach is all wrong. You want to look into using arrays in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Could do something like this:

```
var potions = {
 "acacia cerebrodedemonio alejandrita": "¡Has hecho una poción de polimorfar!"
 }

var potionToFind = plantas + " " + partes + " " + gemas
 potions[potionToFind] || return "El brebaje preparado no ha dado resultado..."
```

so you use a JS object to hold all combinations of potions as a key which holds the value of text you want to display for that combination. If nothing is found it will return the message you are using in your else.

Edit: Also this stops huge if or switch statements and will be much faster in looking up the correct text to return

Answer (score 0):

It is my solution:

```
var a=new Array();
a.push("0,17,10,¡Has hecho una poción de polimorfar!");
a.push("1,0,14,¡Has hecho aceite etéreo!");
................
for (var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
  temp=a[i].split(",");
  if (plantas[temp[0]].checked && partes[temp[1]].checked && gemas[temp[2]].checked)
    { 
      texto =temp[3];
      break;
    }
}
```